# session setting in el and getting java class

Tags: java, jsp, session

How we can set value in session using EL and get That value in java class ie

```
<c:set var="hai" value="${listfiles[8]}" scope="session" />
```

above is a code in my jsp.My code in java class is

```
session.getAttribute("hai").
```

is this possible or not.Have any other method possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the session using scriptlets in jsp.

```
<%  
List name = request.getParameter("name");
if((name!=null)) 
{
 session.setAttribute("hai",name);
  }
%>
```

Change the code according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:set var="Hai" value="myvalue" />
<c:out value="${sessionScope[Hai]}"/>
```

See :

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaim.html